# Unable to use resolution higher than 1280x1024

Tags: counter-strike-condition-zero

(On Windows 7 with ATI Radeon 65xx graphics card) I have a 1920x1080 screen, but am unable to go beyond 1280x1024 resolution. Is it a limitation of the graphics card, some driver issue, or is it the max resolution that CS:CZ supports?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ingame settings only show the default resolutions. To set it to a higher resolution:

1. Open your Steam game library
2. Right click on CSCZ and select `Properties`
3. Click on `Set Launch Options`
4. Enter `-w 1920 -h 1080` and accept

CSCZ will now run at 1920x1080.

Comment: I found that solution online, but I'm not using the Steam version. Can these parameters be added to the non-steam version's shortcut, perhaps?

Comment: @Sumesh yes they should be, even though your version doesn't use Steam the game itself is still a Source game

Comment: So, do I add these parameters to the target field in properties of the CSCZ shortcut?

Comment: @Sumesh - Yes, it should have the same effect.

Comment: Excellent, glad it worked for you :)